# Redirect user to a particular link in 10 seconds after using wp_die

Tags: plugin-development, redirect, http

I want to use some type of functionality

```
if ( $some_condition == false )
{
    wp_die();
    // Here i want to redirect page on some URL after 10 seconds
}
```

I need to do it inside a plugin. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Why use `wp_die()` function? why not just add in your redirect function with the 10second delay?

Comment: Is your site hosted on wordpress.com. If yes, your question is off topic and should be better asked on their support forum. If you site is self hosted, please remove the wordpress.com tag

Comment: Its self hosted. removed the comment

Comment: @MattRoyal `wp_die()` renders a specific template which might the users are familiar with. It also sends a correct status header by a given integer status code.

Answer (score 5):

`wp_die()` terminates the script execution and sends itself a 500 status header (wich can be altered by the third parameter). So you need to send the [`Refresh` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768983/2169046) before the `wp_die()` call. I also recommend to print the redirect location to the body because it's up to the client to respect the refresh header.

```
if ( $condition ) {
    $location = 'http://pm.dev';
    $timeout  = 5;
    $message  = 'You will be redirected to <a href="' . $location . '">' . $location . '</a>';
    $title    = 'Your title';
    $status   = 303; # this might be debatable

    header( 'Refresh: ' . $timeout . ';' . $location );
    wp_die( $message, $title, array( 'response' => $status ) );
}
```

(I'm not sure about the correct [status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4).)

**Note:** As this code sends HTTP Headers, there must no other output sent to the browser before this code.